# Error on AIX 7.3: Relocation entry 0 (at address 0x4BD43) has an invalid l_rsecnm field

Tags: gcc, g++, aix

We get below error with few executables compiled on AIX 7.3 using gcc/g++

root@bp2-aixlpar-om-aix73 # bin/pdconfig
Could not load program bin/pdconfig:
Relocation failed for /test/rahul/otos/lib/libotds.1.so because:
Relocation entry 0 (at address 0x4BD43)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 1 (at address 0x4BD43)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 2 (at address 0x4ECD3)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 3 (at address 0x4ECD3)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 4 (at address 0x4F643)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 5 (at address 0x4F643)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 6 (at address 0x4FD63)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 7 (at address 0x4FD63)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 8 (at address 0x50443)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 9 (at address 0x50443)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 10 (at address 0x50B43)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 11 (at address 0x50B43)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 12 (at address 0x516D3)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 13 (at address 0x516D3)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 14 (at address 0x52473)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 15 (at address 0x52473)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 16 (at address 0x52A53)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 17 (at address 0x52A53)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 18 (at address 0x531C3)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 19 (at address 0x531C3)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 20 (at address 0x543C3)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 21 (at address 0x543C3)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 22 (at address 0x55663)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 23 (at address 0x55663)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 24 (at address 0x58093)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Relocation entry 25 (at address 0x58093)
has an invalid l_rsecnm field.
Examine .loader section relocation entries with the 'dump -Rv' command.

root@bp2-aixlpar-om-aix73 # g++ --version
gcc (GCC) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@bp2-aixlpar-om-aix73 # uname -a
AIX bp2-aixlpar-om-aix73 3 7 00C4D5F04B00

We use below commands to compile the libraries

g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o AuthOTDS.o AuthOTDS.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o Helpers.o Helpers.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o OTDSConnector.o OTDSConnector.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o UserGroupOpOTDS.o UserGroupOpOTDS.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o UserOpOTDS.o UserOpOTDS.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o Connection.o Connection.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o JsonUtil.o JsonUtil.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o RestClient.o RestClient.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o OTDSConfig.o OTDSConfig.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o AppOrigin.o AppOrigin.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o RestClientWrapper.o RestClientWrapper.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o OTDSConnectorWrapper.o OTDSConnectorWrapper.cpp
g++ -Wl,-brtl -maix64 -fPIC -DUSE_EXP_BUF -DAIX -I/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/include/  -c -o OcpOTDS.o OcpOTDS.cpp

ld -bshared -bnotextro -o libotds.1.so `cat libotds.1.lst` -b64 -G -bnoentry -bnolibpath -bnoipath -bexpall -bE:libotds.1.exp   -L/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/lib  -lcurl -lC -lc_r

libotds.1.so is linked to another library libms.2.so. Below command is used to build this library
ld -bshared -o libms.2.so `cat libms.2.lst` -b64 -G -bnoentry -bnolibpath -bnoipath -bexpall -bE:libms.2.exp -L/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/lib /eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/lib/libotds.1.so -lc_r

libms.2.so ultimately gets linked to the executables (ex. pdconfig)

Below are the dependencies
bash-4.3# ldd lib/libotds.1.so
lib/libotds.1.so needs:
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libcurl.so
/usr/lib/libc_r.a(shr_64.o)
/opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a(shr.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libcryptootom.a(libcryptootom64.so.3)
/usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libsslotom.a(libsslotom64.so.3)
/unix
/usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
/usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)

bash-4.3# ldd lib/libms.2.so
lib/libms.2.so needs:
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libotds.1.so
/usr/lib/libc_r.a(shr_64.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libcurl.so
/unix
/usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
/opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a(shr.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libcryptootom.a(libcryptootom64.so.3)
/usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libsslotom.a(libsslotom64.so.3)
/usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)

bash-4.3# ldd bin/pdconfig
bin/pdconfig needs:
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libcurl.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libdazelObject.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libms.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libdazeldb.3.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/Drivers/lib/libodbc.a(odbc.so)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libsnmp_abs.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libsgml.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libutility.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libserver_utils.3.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libserver_pdb.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libidsapi.3.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libidscommon.3.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libxmlutils.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libxml2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libauthz.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libauthzcommon.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libQS.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libinc.3.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libdazel.3.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libasn1cebuf.2.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libsnmp.so
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libathread.1.so
/usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
/usr/lib/libc_r.a(shr_64.o)
/opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a(shr.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libcryptootom.a(libcryptootom64.so.3)
/usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libsslotom.a(libsslotom64.so.3)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libotds.1.so
/usr/lib/libC.a(ansi_64.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/Drivers/lib/libddicu28.a(ddicu28.so)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/Drivers/lib/libodbcinst.a(odbcinst.so)
/usr/lib/libC.a(shr_64.o)
/usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
/usr/lib/libiconv.a(shr4_64.o)
/test/rahul/otos/lib/libjson-c.so
/unix
/usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
/usr/lib/libC.a(shrcore_64.o)
/usr/lib/libC.a(ansicore_64.o)
/usr/lib/libC.a(shr2_64.o)

We have been using xlC to compile the same code on AIX 7.1.
Now we are trying to use gcc/g++ to compile it

Comment: Try linking with g++ e.g. `g++ -shared -Wl,-btextro -o libotds.1.so $(cat libotds.1.lst) -maix64 -Wl,-bE:libotds.1.exp -L/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/24.2.0.0.0.good/exports/lib -lcurl`

Comment: Thank you. This worked and I could move forward. Now I am trying to fix similar problem with other library